# Why does my app look different when running against iOS 6 vs iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios7

Here is what I have it set to look like in Interface Builder. The guidelines show that I can put it right up to the inherited nav bar like this:

[image]

When running against iOS 7 is looks and works fine:

[image]

But against iOS 6 it looks like the UIImageView is being pushed down a good amount, about the height of the nav bar:

[image]

Why is this happening only for iOS 6?

Comment: "Why does my app look different when running against iOS 6 vs iOS 7?" - every iOS developer ever when first faced with Ive's insane creature.

Comment: Fixed the title, saw @H2CO3's comment, *had* to fix his comment too.

Comment: @BoltClock (At least we agree on something, finally :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer...

My controls where copy/pasted from an iOS 6 only project to my new iOS 7/6 project. When I add a new fresh UIImageView to the project, it performs as expected.

Lesson of the day: Don't copy/paste controls into an iOS 7 project and expect them to function properly.